Wife of a rich man haunted by an undertaker who looks like her dead mother
A woman married to a rich man is haunted by an undertaker [probably shown to be 2 undertakers (twins) later]; they look like her dead mother.
The woman kills the undertaker with a cross-shaped knife or dagger, given to her by a priest a day before; police informs her that the priest she claims to have given her the dagger died 2 days ago! (a day before he gave her the dagger).
The movie is in English and was probably from the 90s or early 2000s.

Is there any more information that may help identification? When did you watch it? What time was it likely from? What country was it likely from? Any other story details? Anything?

I was a kid when i watched that, and it was terrifying for a kid :D. More detials in the edit, its probably its in the 90s or early 2000

Added the info. Was it in English?

Yes, it was in english

Could it be Almost Dead from 1994 with Shannen Doherty? I've been having the same doubt for the last 15 years and I think I've finally found it!

Youuuuuuu are the maaaaaaaaan !

Holy crap, I'd flesh out the answer but this movie's not even on Wikipedia.

@Mizunokoe - if you log in as your "Marco" account, you will be able to comment.
